# Speed up Waveform in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I would like to speed up sounds in LabVIEW to get chipmunk sounds. It seems to me this would be done by changing the `dt` for the waveform of the sound, thereby changing the time associated with each `Y` value, but that seems to have no effect. How is it done? And what does changing `dt` do?
For reference, my VI is [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B8oYOiw5gLQXbUEyV0RkaG1FOUU/edit?usp=sharing), I am concerned about the "helium" and "heavy gas" cases.

Comment: What code do you exactly have? How do you output the sound? It's hard to help without any code.

Comment: I have added a link in my question, but most of the stuff I just copped from the sound examples that come with labview anyways.

Comment: I output sound using the "sound output write" VI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is in the output configuration of the Sound output VI. That actually controls the generation speed of the output:
[image]

Comment: That would work for the first iteration, but I want it to store the new play speed for the next playthrough. Is the only way to do it to add another fed back variable?

Comment: Well, you can adjust the Output sample speed for each iteration. However I would not use a feedback for storing variables. Look at some design documents by NI about storing configurations.

Comment: Does that include storing waveforms? Should I not use a feedback for it? 

Also would a solution then be to pull the `dt` out of my waveform and use that to set my sample rate?

And whats the use of including a `dt` if subVI's reading the waveform don't actually look at it?

Comment: You could consider it a bug that the the dt in the waveform is not used by the sound output VIs. Your code is made to run from instance to instance, not the best method. I would use a state machine. (An easy example is the JKI State machine toolkit at http://jki.net/state-machine)